# update only selected model fields

Tags: python, django

i have a list of tasks each task has a button edit for updating it ,
  in my update view

```
class TaskUpdate(UpdateView):

    model = Task
    fields = ['titre', 'objectif', 'date', 'theme']
```

## urls.py

```
url(r'^edit_task/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.TaskUpdate.as_view(), name='TaskUpdate'),
```

the html code of edit button

```
<td><a href="{%url "TaskUpdate" task.id  %}"><button type="button"/><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true" />edit</td>
```

when i click on the button edit i get this error : TemplateDoesNotExist at /edit_task/9/
app/task_form.html

i don't have task_form.html i don't know where it comes from please help me , thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the default for an update view is to call a model (in this case a Task's) form.

Thus when you call TaskUpdate it searches for the nonexistent form. You might have to make a non-custom form.

"A view that displays a form for editing an existing object, redisplaying the form with validation errors (if there are any) and saving changes to the object. This uses a form automatically generated from the object’s model class (unless a form class is manually specified)"

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview